# 404 after joining Bitcoin Stack Exchange

Tags: bug, user-accounts

I clicked 'Join this Community' on https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com, then I 'Confirmed', then I received a 404 page:

[image]

Comment: Did you take full screenshot showing the URL? Do you remember what page you were on when clicking the "Join" button?

Comment: Were you on the main site or the meta site? I had this before when I was trying to join a community from the meta site and found that it worked from the main site.